# VBA - Check if an Item exists in a collection and if exists clear selection of other items in the listbox but not that item

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to check if a particular item called as "All" exists in a collection.

```
  Private Sub RefreshData_ListBox_Change()

    Dim ListBoxSelected As Collection
    Set ListBoxSelected = New Collection
    LbKey = 0

    Dim ReqValue As String
    Dim ItemReq As String

    For lItem = 0 To SelectRequiredQR.RefreshData_ListBox.ListCount - 1

        If SelectRequiredQR.RefreshData_ListBox.Selected(lItem) = True Then

            LbKey = LbKey + 1

            ReqValue = SelectRequiredQR.RefreshData_ListBox.List(lItem)

            ListBoxSelected.Add ReqValue, CStr(LbKey)

        End If

    Next

    TotalItems = ListBoxSelected.Count

    If TotalItems > 1 Then
```

> if total item is more than 1 - then I want to check for an item
>   called     as "All" inside the listbox and if that exist then I want to clear
>   the selection     of other items    in the listbox but not 'ALL"

```
        For i = 1 To TotalItems

            ItemReq = ListBoxSelected(i)


            If ItemReq = "ALL" Then


                For j = TotalItems To 0 Step -1

                    ItemReq = ListBoxSelected(j)


                    If ItemReq <> "ALL" Then

                        'Remove Item from collection 
                        ListBoxSelected.Remove (j)

                        'Remove selection from listbox
                        SelectRequiredQR.RefreshData_ListBox.Selected(j) = True

                    End If

                Next

            End If

        Next

    End If
```

Comment: Try a `For` loop to validate `RefreshData_ListBox(i).Value`

Comment: @DavidG. Tried that, but my code to remove selection from listbox isn't working for me.

Comment: `SelectRequiredQR.RefreshData_ListBox.Selected(j) = **False**`

Comment: Beware of recursion; changing the Selected flags triggers the Change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that if the user selects the All item, any other items should be unselected. Then you could go along those lines:

```
Private Sub RefreshData_ListBox_Change()
    Static bWorking As Boolean
    Dim lItem As Long
    Dim lUnselect As Long

    'Check the anti-recursion flag.        
    If Not bWorking Then
        For lItem = 0 To RefreshData_ListBox.ListCount - 1
            If RefreshData_ListBox.Selected(lItem) Then
                If StrComp(RefreshData_ListBox.List(lItem), "All", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    'Manage recursion.
                    bWorking = True

                    For lUnselect = 0 To RefreshData_ListBox.ListCount - 1
                        If lUnselect <> lItem Then
                            RefreshData_ListBox.Selected(lUnselect) = False
                        End If
                    Next

                    bWorking = False
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```